# How to prevent changes to the underlying file after mmap()-ing a file from being visible to my program?

Tags: linux, file, locking, mmap, copy-on-write

According to [mmap()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) manpage:

> MAP_PRIVATE
>
> Create a private copy-on-write mapping.  Updates to the mapping are not visible to other processes mapping the same file, and are not carried through to the underlying file.  **It is unspecified whether changes made to the file after the mmap() call are visible in the mapped region.**

**Question**: How to prevent changes to the underlying file after mmap()-ing a file from being visible to my program?

---

**Background**: I am designing a data structure for a text editor designed to allow editing huge text files efficiently. The data structure is akin to an on-disk [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_(data_structure)) but with the actual strings being pointer to mmap()-ed ranges from the original file.

Since the file could be very large, there are a few restrictions around the design:

1. Must not load the entire file into RAM as the file may be larger than available physical RAM
2. Must not copy files on opening as this will make opening new files really slow
3. Must work on filesystems like ext4 that does not support copy-on-write (`cp --reflink`/`ioctl_ficlone`)
4. Must not rely on mandatory file locking, as this is deprecated, and requires specific mount option `-o mand` in the filesystem
5. As long as the changes aren't visible in my mmap(), it's ok for the underlying file to change on the filesystem
6. Only need to support recent Linux and using Linux-specific system APIs are ok

The data structure I'm designing would keep track of a list of unedited and edited ranges in the file by storing start and end index of the ranges into the mmap()-ed buffer. While the user is browsing through the file, ranges of text that have never been modified by the user would be read directly from a `mmap()` of the original file, while a swap file will store the ranges of texts that have been edited by the user but had not been saved.

When the user saves a file, the data structure would use [copy_file_range](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html) to splice the swap file and the original file to assemble the new file. For this splicing to work, the original file as seen by my program must remain unchanged throughout the entire editing session.

**Problem**: The user may concurrently have other programs modifying the same file, possibly other text editors or some other programs that modified the text file in-place, after making unsaved changes in my text editor.

In such situation, the editor can detect such external change using inotify, and then I want to give the user two options on how to continue from this:

1. discard all unsaved changes and re-read the file from disk, implementing this option is fairly straightforward
2. allow the user to continue editing the file and later on the user should be able to save the unsaved changes in a new location or to overwrite the changes that had been made by the other program, but implementing this seems tricky

Since my editor did not make a copy of the file when it opened the file, when the other program overwrite the file, the text ranges that my data structure are tracking may become invalid because the data on-disk have changed and these changes are now visible through my `mmap()`. This means if my editor tried to write unsaved changes after the file has been modified from another process, it could be splicing text ranges in the old file using data from the data from the new file, which could mean that my editor could be producing a corrupt file when saving the unsaved changes.

I don't think advisory locks would have saved the situation here in all cases, as other programs may not honor advisory lock.

My ideal solution would be to make it so that when other programs overwrites the file, the system should transparently copy the file to allow my program to continue seeing the old version while the other program finishes their write to disk and make their version visible in the filesystem. I think ioctl_ficlone could have made this possible, but to my understanding, this only works with a copy-on-write filesystem like btrfs.

Is such a thing possible?

---

Any other suggestions to solve this problem would also be welcome.

Comment: If there's no option to `mmap()` to do this, I don't think there's a good solution.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but my suggestion would be to not jump through hoops to try to protect the user from themself. Advisory locks and a warning on modification is plenty. If a user wants to destroy a file, Unix offers a hundred more convenient footguns than to ignore locks and warnings in a large file editor.

Comment: Maybe not what you are looking for, but why not use the Linux user/group mechanism to forbid access/writing to other processes: just create a new user for your editor and set the appropriate access rights, maybe 744? that way, only root could mess your file.

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do isn't possible with `mmap`, and I'm not sure if it's possible at all with your constraints.

When you map a region, the kernel may or may not actually load all of it into memory. The region of memory that lacks data will actually contain an invalid page, so when you access it, the kernel takes a page fault and maps that region into memory. That region will likely contain whatever is in that portion of the file at the time the page fault occurs. There is an option, `MAP_LOCKED`, which *tries* to prefault all of the pages in, but doesn't guarantee it, so you can't rely on it working.

In general, you cannot prevent other processes from changing a file out from under you. Some tools (including editors) will write a new file to the side, calling `rename` to overwrite the file, and some will rewrite the file in place. The former is  what you want, but many editors choose to do the latter, since it preserves characteristics such as ACLs and permissions you can't restore.

Furthermore, you really don't want to use `mmap` on any file you can't totally control, because if another process truncates the file and you try to access that portion of the buffer, your process will die with `SIGBUS`. Catching this signal is undefined behavior, and the only sane thing to do is die. (Also, it can be sent in other situations, such as unaligned access, and you'll have a hard time distinguishing between them.)

Ultimately, if you're not interested in copying the file, you can't guarantee someone won't change underneath you, and you'll need to be prepared for that to occur.

Answer (score 0):

*Any other suggestions to solve this problem would also be welcome.*

The Linux way to deal with exclusive access to resources (files on disk, serial ports, audio dsps, etc...) is to make use of the user/group mechanism. Make your process the owner of the file and forbid access to anyone but you.

In `man 2 chown` and `man 2 chmod` you can find information about how to do it programmatically. Also, `The Linux programming interface` (chapters 8 and 9) by Michael Kerrisk can give you a more comprehensive explanation of the relevant libraries and system calls.